# store value into namedtuple in python

Tags: python

I have 2 text files that look like the ones below:

**input.txt**

```
shoes
memory card
memory card
```

**input1.txt**

```
shoes
shoes
```

From these two text file I need to find the data in the format like below. I can store it into a namedtuple or dictionary.
in this format:
`unique_query,[count in input.txt, count in input1.txt]`

**op:-**

```
shoes,[1,2]
memory card,[2,0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the contents of the two files into a list. Make two sets out of two lists, and then perform a union operation. Later, use `list.count(..)` to count the occurrences.

Something like the below:

```
>>> with open("input.txt") as f:
...     a1 = [x.strip() for x in f]
>>> with open("input1.txt") as f:
...     a2 = [x.strip() for x in f]
>>> set(a1) | set(a2)
set(['memory card', 'shoes'])
>>> [(x, a1.count(x), a2.count(x)) for x in set(a1) | set(a2)]
[('memory card', 2, 0), ('shoes', 1, 2)]
>>> print "\n".join(",".join([x, str([a1.count(x), a2.count(x)])]) for x in set(a1) | set(a2))
memory card,[2, 0]
shoes,[1, 2]
```

---

If you have a large files, you collections.Counter.

```
>>> with open("inp1") as f:
...     c = Counter(x.strip() for x in f)
>>> with open("inp2") as f:
...     c2 = Counter(x.strip() for x in f)
>>> [(x, c[x], c2[x]) for x in set(c) | set(c2)]
[('memory card', 2, 0), ('shoes', 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Maybe change to `[ (x, (a1.count(x), a2.count(x)) ) ]`, just so the pedant in me is satisfied? ;)

Comment: i have large file so i can't write like above.

Comment: i want to do it with namedtuple. can you help me with that.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? If you're going to find patterns frequency between the two files, you have to open *atleast* one file into a iterable/hashable type.

Comment: @mogambo i have to find out the ratio of count of input1.txt as compare to input.txt if the ratio is <=40 then i need to find the data query and count of input1.txt and store it into mysql table.

Comment: @s_m Updated the answer for large files.

Comment: @Thrustmaster   i have to find out the ratio of count of input1.txt as compare to input.txt if the ratio is <=40 then i need to find the data query and count of input1.txt and store it into mysql table

Comment: @Thrustmaster so i think it will be better to store in mysql table.

Comment: Makes sense in your case. I only answered the question present in the original post.

Comment: @Thrustmaster yea i know. can you help me with that.

Comment: Sure, try to come up with a basic implementation. When you get stuck somewhere, create a new question with all the relevant details. :)

Comment: @Thrustmaster can you explain here.